# how to prevent class 'a' from being inherited by another class?

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, programming-languages

I have a class named `fdetails` and I do not want any other class to inherit from this class.

Can I set it to not being inherited by another class. I would like to get this done in the following 3 languages:

- Java
- VB.NET 3.5
- C# 3.5

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
java: final  
vb: NotInheritable (NonOverrideable for properties)
c#: sealed
```

Comment: c#: you can create private constructor to restrict inheritance also.

Comment: By using `final`, still you can can inherit it: "inner class"

Answer (score 11):

In Java use the final keyword:

```
public final class fdetails{

}
```

In C# use the sealed keyword:

```
public sealed class fdetails{

}
```

In VB.net use the NotInheritable keyword:

```
public notinheritable class fdetails

end class
```

Answer (score 4):

In C# you use the `sealed` keyword in order to prevent a class from being inherited.

In VB.NET you use the `NotInheritable` keyword.

In Java you use the keyword `final`.

Answer (score 3):

In JAVA - use the final keyword:

```
public final class FDetails
```

In C# - the sealed keyword:

```
sealed class FDetails
```

Comment: `static` isn't required for the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent a class in C# from being inherited, the keyword sealed is used. Thus a sealed class may not serve as a base class of any other class. It is also obvious that a sealed class cannot be an abstract class. Code below...

```
//C# Example
sealed class ClassA
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

No class can inherit from ClassA defined above. Instances of ClassA may be created and its members may then be accessed, but nothing like the code below is possible...

```
class DerivedClass : ClassA { } // Error
```

Same in Java and VB.net:

```
java: final  
vb: NotInheritable (NonOverrideable for properties)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4096427/5292885 answer, one can create the base class with private constructor to avoid inheritance (in C#, you get error like **the class is inaccessible due to its protection level** in case if you refer the base class)

Comment: Sure, but if the stated problem is that the class not be inheritable (i.e., not extensible), then use the language mechanism that is expressly for that purpose -- in Java, that is ```final``` -- not some other construct that has non-inheritability as a sort of side effect.   A private constructor prevents much more than inheritance!

Comment: Yep as i mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/4096427/5292885  is the cleanest way of preventing inheritance

Answer (score 0):

For C#, it's the "sealed" keyword.

For Java, it's the "final" keyword.